# Minecraft pe yaw have more than 360 and less 0 degrees

Tags: javascript, math, minecraft

I have the meaning yaw which is expressed in radians and I will convert to degrees. But if the player rotates more than 360 degrees, yaw is not reset to 0. Also if the player rotates in the negative direction, the value will be less than 0. The value can be more and less than 360, but I need a interval from 0 to 360 degrees, how to do this?

```
function rtd(r) {
  var pi = Math.PI;
  return Math.floor(r * (180 / pi));
}
function getYaw(rotation) {
  var yawRTD = rtd(rotation.yaw);
  var yaw = 0;
  yaw = yawRTD;
  if (yaw > 360) {
    yaw -= 360
  };
  if (yaw < 360) {
    yaw += 360
  };
  return yaw;
}
```

Comment: Why ``yawRTD/360 > 1``, Why not  ``yawRTD < 360 && yawRTD > 0`` and else will be ``yaw = 0`` ? Explain me please

Comment: @deoncagadoes In the code, I incorrectly described the problem itself. I need the variable to always be only from 0 to 360, but yaw always have more than 360 or less than 0 degrees

Comment: I make you answer on comment, you say you want a reset to 0 when more than 360 ? OK , make if more than 360, be yaw 360 and when lower than 0 be 0...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for this question is

```
function rtd(r) {
  var pi = Math.PI;
  return Math.floor(r * (180 / pi));
}
function getYaw(rotation) {
  var yawRTD = rtd(rotation.yaw);
  var yaw = 0;
  // reduce yaw 
  yaw = yawRTD%360;
  // force it to be the positive remainder, so that 0 <= yaw < 360 
  yaw =(yaw +360)%360;
  return yaw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust with a remainder of 360 and add 360 for getting a positive value and take from this the remainder value.

```js
function getDegree(d) {
    return (d % 360 + 360) % 360;
}

console.log(...[-720, -10, 0, 30, 390, 1000].map(getDegree)); // 0 350 0 30 30 280
```